# How to fill String[] array in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a method in java just like this and I want to convert it to kotlin. I wrote a method in kotlin but array does not fill and I have null array in return. how can I fix that? Thank in Advance.

**Java code**

```
private String[] getNameOfPersonalityTpye(List<PersonalityTpye> list){
        String[] s = new String[list.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            s[i] = list.get(i).getPersonalityTypeName();
        }
        return s;
    }
```

**Kotlin code**

```
private fun getNameOfPersonalityTpye(list: List<PersonalityTpye>): Array<String?>{
        val s=  arrayOfNulls<String>(list.size);
        for(i in list.indices){
            s[i] = list[i].name;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Are your sure the list you are passing contains any value?

Comment: @Dennis Yeah I'm sure. I checked it 2 times

Comment: Try printing `list[i].name` in console, do you see anything?

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I can see all 4 items in list when I debug it. I'm steel wondering why s array does not fill just like java method

Comment: I mean did you explicitly `println(list[i].name)` ? I mean what if it's returning a null value?

Comment: In Java, you use `getPersonalityTypeName`, in Kotlin you use `.name` which corresponds to Java `getName`. If you use the same method, you should see the same result, because code is otherwise equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

With `map` and `toTypedArray()`:

```
private fun getNameOfPersonalityType(list: List<PersonalityType>) = list.map { it.name }.toTypedArray()
```

I guess it's `Type` and not `Tpye`
Just check the `size` after. If it is `0` then the list was empty.
If the list passed as parameter may contain `null` values, then change to this:

```
private fun getNameOfPersonalityType(list: List<PersonalityType?>) = list.mapNotNull { it?.name }.toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working perfectly fine

```
private fun check(){
        val list = ArrayList<String>()
        list.add("json")
        list.add("statham")
        println("value from array "+getNameOfPersonalityTpye(list)[1]) //prints statham
    }

    private fun getNameOfPersonalityTpye(list:List<String>): Array<String?>{
        val s=  arrayOfNulls<String>(list.size)
        for(i in s.indices){
            s[i] = list[i]
        }
        return s
    }
```

So this `list[i].name;` in your code might be `null`. Otherwise everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with `Stream`

```
private fun getNameOfPersonalityTpye(list: List<PersonalityTpye>): Array<String> {
    return list.stream().map<Any> { e -> e.getPersonalityTypeName() }.toArray() as Array<String>
}
```